# (MySQL) не могу написать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день. Собственно не могу написать SQL запрос, особо не силен в этом, но появилась одна задача, собственно поэтому решил попросить помощи.

Имеется база данных, с двумя таблицами **[customers]** и **[orders]**, в таблице **[customers]** содержится около **1 млн.** записей, в таблице **[orders]** содержится около **1.5 млн.** записей.

Структура таблицы **[customers]**: `id, firstname, lastname, email, date_reg`

Структура таблицы **[orders]**:  `id, customer_id, total, status, order_date`

Собственно необходимо сделать две выборки:

- **TOP 500 [customers]** за последний год, у которых нет ни одного **[orders]** где

**[status]** = **success**, сортировка по **[date_reg]**.

- **TOP 500 [orders]** созданных в будний день за последние 3 месяца вывести **[order_id]**, **[email]**, **[date_order]** сортировка по **[date_order]** заказа.

**UPDATE**
Немного почитав, собрал такой запрос.

```
SELECT customers.id, 
       customers.firstname, 
       customers.lastname, 
       orders.status 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders 
ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
AND orders.status != 'success' 
AND customers.registration_date >= '2016-05-01' 
LIMIT 500;
```

В принципе он почти во всем меня устраивает кроме того что, по условию нужно вывести только клиентов у которых вообще не было ни единого "success" заказа. А в моем случае как я понял я вывожу все не "success" заказы клиентов, которые были зарегистрированы на протяжении прошедшего года.

Comment: Что вы уже сделали для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, у меня получилось сделать выборку пользователей за последний год, но я не знаю как объединить выборку пользователей вместе с проверкой по таблице **orders** на статус заказа.

Comment: Получите в подзапросе количество заказов с нужным статусом за последний год, и отберите тех, у кого оно нулевое. Используйте полученный набор записей для отбора в основном запросе.

Comment: @Akina мне нужно вывести не заказы за последний год, а зарегистрированных посетителей, у которых нет не единого "success" заказа

Comment: Это и из самогО вопроса понятно. Вот поэтому и подзапрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TOP 500 [customers] за последний год, у которых нет ни одного [orders] где
   [status] = success, сортировка по [date_reg]

   ```
   select c.id
   from customers c
       join orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
   where date(date_reg) >= curdate() - interval 1 year /* за последний год */
   group by c.id
   having sum(if(status = 'success', 1, 0)) = 0 /* кол-во заказов со статусом success = 0 */
   order by c.date_reg desc
   limit 500
   ```
2. TOP 500 [orders] созданных в будний день за последние 3 месяца вывести [order_id], [email], [date_order] сортировка по [date_order] заказа

   ```
   select o.id as order_id,
       c.email,
       o.order_date
   from orders o
       join customers c ON o.customer_id = c.id
   where date(order_date) >= curdate() - interval 3 month
       and dayofweek between 2 and 6 /* 1 - вс, 7 - сб */
   order by order_date desc
   limit 500
   ```